# SQL Server : creating a procedure/trigger to create a new order for every type of another order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

As a beginner, I am looking for assistance on trying to create an order for every time another order appears.

I have 3 order types in the table `dbo.OrderType` with columns `OrderTypeID, OrderTypeName`:

```
OrderTypeID   OrderTypeName
---------------------------
     1        Assignment
     2        LoanRelease
     3        DocumentRetrieval
```

For every order with `OrderTypeName = Assignment` I need to create an `Order` with 
`OrderTypeName = DocumentRetrieval`

Here are the tables I believe I need,

**dbo.tblOrder**

Columns: `OrderId, OrderTypeID, LoanNumber`, and `CustomerID`

**dbo.tblOrderActivity**

Columns: `OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate`

**dbo.tblActivity**

Columns `ActivityID, ActivityName`

```
ActivityID  ActivityName
------------------------
     1      Received
     2      Keyed
     3      Printed
     4      Delivered
```

**dbo.tblCustomer**

Columns `CustomerID, CustomerName`

I believe I need to create a procedure for this since it relates to creating a new `Order` with the `OrderType = 3` for every `Order` with `OrderType = 1`, every new order created must have the `received` or `ActivityID = 1`.

Can someone help me start the logic and process of this?

Here is a trigger creation I have started with, however, I can not get it to execute due to syntax errors, and still need to figure out how to create not just the new `Order` and `OrderTypeID(3)` for every Order with `OrderTypeID(1)`

But also to create the a new `OrderActivity` with `ActivityID = 1`

```
create trigger trg_Order ON dbo.tblOrder
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.tblOrder
IF exists (select 1 from inserted where OrderTypeId = 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.tblOrder 
    SELECT OrderID,3,LoanNumber,CustomerID
    FROM inserted
    WHERE OrderTypeID = 1       
END
END
```

Comment: post what you have (even if it contains errors) and we'll try to help you get through it :)

Comment: I assume that the `Order` and `OrderActivity` rows should be duplicated. The `Activity` and `OrderType` rows I'd say obviously not. The `Customer` one is slightly ambiguous. You may want new rows in that table, or you may want to re-use the existing rows (Arguments can be made either way) - can you specify which you want?

Comment: Yes, a new Order(OrderID(autoincrement) and OrderTypeID(3)) consisting of that OrderTypeID for DocumentRetrieval, created for every Order that is of OrderTypeID(1)"Assignment". So the new Order being created will have the same LoanNumber and CustomerID as the one it is being created for. So then when relating to the OrderActivity Table, the OrderID will be the OrderID created from the new Order being created, having the ActivityID(1) for received.   Basically creating a new "DocumentRetrieval" type of order for every "assignment" type order.

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger trg_Order on dbo.tblorder
after insert
as
BEGIN
if exists ( select 1 from inserted where orderTypeId = 1)
    BEGIN
     insert into dbo.tblorder
    select OrderId,3,LoanNumber, customerid
    from inserted
    where OrderTypeId = 1

    insert into dbo.tblorderActivity
    select OrderId,1,sysdatetime()
    from inserted
    where OrderTypeId = 1
END
END
```

This was the code that was ended up successfully doing what I needed.